# git revert : Unable to undo an individual commit even in a simple case

Tags: git-revert

In order to try and understand `git revert`, I made a series of 4 simple commits -- A, B, C, D -- to a text file, `foo.txt`, with the intention of undoing only commit B later and leaving commits A, C, D intact.

So, in each commit, I added a new line each to the file, emulating either a feature added or a bug introduced.

**After commit A, contents of `foo.txt`:**

```
Feature A
```

**After commit B, contents of `foo.txt`:** *(Here, I introduce a bug that I'll later try to undo/revert.)*

```
Feature A
Bug
```

**After commit C, contents of `foo.txt`:**

```
Feature A
Bug
Feature C
```

**After commit D, contents of `foo.txt`:**

```
Feature A
Bug
Feature C
Feature D
```

Now, to undo the effects of Commit B (which introduced the bug), I did:

```
git revert master^^
```

What I expected to happen was, a new Commit E that removed the `Bug` line from the file, leaving the file contents as:

```
Feature A
Feature C
Feature D
```

However, I got the error:

```
error: could not revert bb58ed3... Bug introduced
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

with the contents of the file following the unsuccessful `git revert` being:

```
Feature A
<<<<<<< HEAD
Bug
Feature C
Feature D
=======
>>>>>>> parent of bb58ed3... Bug introduced
```

( *bb58ed3* is the hash of Commit B, and *'Bug introduced'* this commit's comment.)

**Question:**

1. What is going on here?
2. If even such a simple, one-line commit cannot be reverted/undone automatically, and must require manual resolution from me, then how could I revert a much more complex commit whose original developer may even be someone else!
3. Is there a special set of cases where `git revert` would be better applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git` sees each commit as a changelist (I simplify things here) and tries to "unapply" that when you call `git revert`. Each changelist also includes some context to ensure that the change makes sense. For example, if the change we want to make is "add `return` after line 10", it's more likely to break things than "add `return` after line 10, if lines 7-9 contain X, Y, and Z". So, we can describe your second commit as (again, simplifying this a little here):

1. Assuming that the first line of the file is `Feature A`.
2. Assuming that there is no second line.
3. Make the second line contain `Bug`.

After you've added few more lines, context of the `Bug` changed significantly, so `git revert` is not sure whether it can simply remove the line. Maybe the newly added lines actually fixed the bug. So it asks you to explicitly resolve the conflict of contexts.

As for your questions 2-3: yes, `git revert` is usable in cases when you're reverting a piece of file which was not changed since then. For example, the bug was introduced in a `foo` function, but only `bar` function (which is located ten lines below) was modified since then. In that case, `git revert` is likely to automatically revert the change, because it sees that the context is unchanged.

**UPD**: here is an example of why context matters even if you're trying to revert your own code:

Commit A (mind the mistype):

```
int some_vlue = 0;
read_int_into(some_vlue);
some_vlue = some_vlue++;
```

Commit B (bug introduced):

```
int some_vlue = 0;
some_vlue = 123;
some_vlue = some_vlue++;
```

Commit C (name fixed):

```
int some_value = 0;
some_value = 123;
some_value = some_value++;
```

Now, in order to revert commit B, one have to have some context, as we cannot simply replace `some_value = 123` with older line `read_int_into(some_vlue)` - it would be compilation error.

Comment: I think, the context thing is hurting more than helping. `git` should allow disabling the use of context via an option to `git revert`. Context would be useful when you're sending patches out and applying them blindly or not knowing fully if they are being applied to the right target and its version. But in cases like mine, `git` itself knows accurately the exact source and target, so why make use of context, I wonder! Appreciate your explanation, btw. I'll wait some more before marking it final.

Comment: @Harry I've added some explanation. There can be more complex situations with variable renames, method renames, and in some of them the resulting code would even compile. So, it's impossible to automatically check whether we can ignore context or not and `git` plays safe.

Comment: Your example definitely makes sense. But, then, how could `git` ever rely on (a limited) context, since renames can happen outside the context also?

Comment: My suggestion is that limited context turned out to be a good balance between "break everything" and "always manually merge changes inside a file" (which also does not help as renaming can happen even in other files).

Comment: Fine! I'm satisfied with your responses, thanks! But still, IMHO, what `git` should be doing is providing the user an option to ignore the context and maybe also leave the result uncommitted giving the user a chance to resolve compilation errors, if any.